# WordPress Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress

Существует каталог (каждая страница каталога имеет тип поста **page**)
Существует список товаров (каждый товар имеет кастомный тип поста **product**)

Для каждого товара я могу задать в качестве родительской только post type product.
Мне необходимо выбрать, естественно, в качестве родительской, для каждого товара post type page

Каким образом я могу это реализовать?

```
function create_products() {

  $labels = array(
    'name' => __('Товары'),
    'singular_name' => __('Товар'),
    'add_new' => __('Добавить новый'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Добавить новый товар'),
    'edit_item' => __('Редактировать товар'),
    'new_item' => __('Добавить новый товар'),
    'view_item' => __('Просмотр товара'),
    'search_items' => __('Найти товар'),
    'not_found' => __('Товар не найденг'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Товар не найден в корзине'),
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Товары'
  );
  $supports = array(
    'title',
    'editor',
    'thumbnail',
    'author',
    'revisions',
    'page-attributes',
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'supports' => $supports,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/', 'with_front' => false),
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-cart',
    'has_archive' => false,
  );

  register_post_type('product', $args);

}

add_action('init', 'create_products');
```

Comment: У тебя в первой строчке ошибка - этого не надо делать вообще. Каталог сформируется сам, автоматически. По остальному не ясно  что надо.

Comment: Да нет, мне его нужно вручную формировать